# Creating a random image swap and inhibiting mouseover events

Tags: javascript

I was trying to create a little block of code that puts an image on an HTML page and then when the user hovers over it a new image appears each time. The problem with my code is if you move the mouse at all inside the image the various images flicker erratically since the mouseover event isn't halted. Another small problem is I couldn't get it to work without an empty placeholder at the 0 index in the array.

I am more curious about how I should be looking at the problem than the actual solution.

```
<div id="myImage">
    <img id="theImg" src="whatever.png" alt="yay" height="42" width="42">
</div>

<script>

    imgs = ['placeholder','house','piggy','food'];

    $('#myImage').mouseenter(function(){

        $( "#theImg" ).remove();

        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1;

        $('#myImage').append('<img id="theImg" src=' + imgs[rand]  +'.png' + '>');

        console.log(imgs[rand]);
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the flickering is due to the fact that you're not setting a height or width for the new image element, and therefore the following chain of events is happening:

- `mouseenter` fires causing the removal of the current `img` element, and the insertion of a new one
- there is no width or height information for this new image, so the element shrinks to 0x0 whilst the image data loads
- now that the browser has the image data, it can obtain the width and height directly from the data, and it sets the `img` to have these dimensions
- the `img` element therefore expands to this size, which causes it to expand under the cursor, and hence another `mouseenter` event fires

To avoid this, either set a width and height on the inserted `img` element, or just change the `src` of the element rather than messing around with removing and inserting elements.

Comment: The height of the image is all it was. I have no idea how I could have  figured that out. The chain of events you mentioned is something that would have never entered my mind.